# Boolean statement where extra parenthesis are required

Tags: c#, boolean

```
public class Part
{
    public String VendorId { get; set; }
    public String VendorPart { get; set; }
    public String BasePart { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ImageViewType View { get; set; }
}

private  List<Part> partList = null;

private bool deleteOldFile = false;
```

I'm curious why the following code works (once `partList` is loaded with data):

```
foreach (Part p in partList)
{
    deleteOldFile = ((partList.Last().BasePart) == (p.BasePart));
    MoveFile(FileType.Image, p, GetSetImageFile(imageBox1, currentFile));
}
```

and the following does not work (never sets boolean `deleteOldFile` to true):

```
foreach (Part p in partList)
{
    deleteOldFile = (partList.Last().BasePart == p.BasePart);
    MoveFile(FileType.Image, p, GetSetImageFile(imageBox1, currentFile));
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You shouldn't need even the brackets you've got there - it should be `deleteOldFile = partList.Last().BasePart == p.BasePart;`. Note that the value of `deleteOldFile` after the loop will only be the result for the *last iteration* as you're just overwriting the variable on each iteration. Is that intentional?

Comment: On a side note, calling `partList.Last()` within the `foreach` is going to cause the list to enumerate in every iteration. It might be better to create a `var lastPart = partList.Last().BasePart;` outside of the loop.

Comment: Appreciate the comments.  The intention is to set the value to true on the last iteration only.  The program is designed to take a single file and copy it to multiple unique filenames in a separate folder.  On the last copy the old file is deleted.  Sorry for not explaining the intention or including more of the program.  I just wanted to understand why the first example works fine but the second does not.

Comment: if "The intention is to set the value to true on the last iteration only",  Then the code to do that should not be in the `foreach` loop. Just delete the file on a separate line AFTER the `foreach` loop

Comment: Thanks Charles, I'm seeing the reason I need to include more code.  This is one of several similar foreach loops - the actual move and delete happen in MoveFile.  Though I always appreciate suggestions for programming alternatives, my program is working fine (maybe not elegant but working).  Any ideas on why the boolean evaluation is working in the first example but not the second?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between these two options. The cause of your problem is probably because you override value of `deleteOldFile` every iteration. I think you wanted to write this:

```
foreach (Part p in partList)
{
    deleteOldFile = deleteOldFile || partList.Last().BasePart == p.BasePart;
    MoveFile(FileType.Image, p, GetSetImageFile(imageBox1, currentFile));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are resetting `deleteOldFile` for ebvery item in list.

if you want to deletefile if *any* item is the same as the last item, (except the last item itself of course, which will always be the same as itself), then change to:

```
  var deleteFile = false;
  var last = partList.Last();
  foreach (Part p in partList)
      if (p.Equals(last) || deleteOldFile = (p.BasePart == last.BasePart)) 
          break;
```